# Tree cut issue in WGCNA

Tags: r, rna-seq, wgcna

```
library(WGCNA);
# The following setting is important, do not omit.
library(flashClust)
enableWGCNAThreads()
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE);
#Read in the female liver data set
femData = read.csv("CTRL_WGCNA.txt",sep = "\t");

head(femData)
# Read in the male liver data set
maleData = read.csv("BPD_WGCNA.txt",sep = "\t");
# Take a quick look at what is in the data sets (caution, longish output):
dim(femData)
names(femData)
dim(maleData)
names(maleData)


#=====================================================================================
#
#  Code chunk 2
#
#=====================================================================================


# We work with two sets:
nSets = 2;
# For easier labeling of plots, create a vector holding descriptive names of the two sets.
setLabels = c("Female liver", "Male liver")
shortLabels = c("Female", "Male")
# Form multi-set expression data: columns starting from 9 contain actual expression data.
multiExpr = vector(mode = "list", length = nSets)

multiExpr[[1]] = list(data = as.data.frame(t(femData[-c(1)])));
names(multiExpr[[1]]$data) = femData$Gene;
rownames(multiExpr[[1]]$data) = names(femData)[-c(1)];
multiExpr[[2]] = list(data = as.data.frame(t(maleData[-c(1)])));
names(multiExpr[[2]]$data) = maleData$Gene;
rownames(multiExpr[[2]]$data) = names(maleData)[-c(1)];
# Check that the data has the correct format for many functions operating on multiple sets:
exprSize = checkSets(multiExpr)


#=====================================================================================
#
#  Code chunk 3
#
#=====================================================================================


# Check that all genes and samples have sufficiently low numbers of missing values.
gsg = goodSamplesGenesMS(multiExpr, verbose = 3);
gsg$allOK


#=====================================================================================
#
#  Code chunk 4
#
#=====================================================================================


if (!gsg$allOK)
{
  # Print information about the removed genes:
  if (sum(!gsg$goodGenes) > 0)
    printFlush(paste("Removing genes:", paste(names(multiExpr[[1]]$data)[!gsg$goodGenes], 
                                              collapse = ", ")))
  for (set in 1:exprSize$nSets)
  {
    if (sum(!gsg$goodSamples[[set]]))
      printFlush(paste("In set", setLabels[set], "removing samples",
                       paste(rownames(multiExpr[[set]]$data)[!gsg$goodSamples[[set]]], collapse = ", ")))
    # Remove the offending genes and samples
    multiExpr[[set]]$data = multiExpr[[set]]$data[gsg$goodSamples[[set]], gsg$goodGenes];
  }
  # Update exprSize
  exprSize = checkSets(multiExpr)
}


#=====================================================================================
#
#  Code chunk 5
#
#=====================================================================================


sampleTrees = list()
for (set in 1:nSets)
{
  sampleTrees[[set]] = hclust(dist(multiExpr[[set]]$data), method = "average")
}


#=====================================================================================
#
#  Code chunk 6
#
#=====================================================================================


pdf(file = "SampleClustering.pdf", width = 12, height = 12);
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
par(mar = c(0, 4, 2, 0))
for (set in 1:nSets)
  plot(sampleTrees[[set]], main = paste("Sample clustering on all genes in", setLabels[set]),
       xlab="", sub="", cex = 0.7);
dev.off();


  #=====================================================================================
#
#  Code chunk 7
#
#=====================================================================================


# Choose the "base" cut height for the female data set
baseHeight = 80
# Adjust the cut height for the male data set for the number of samples
cutHeights = c(80, 100*exprSize$nSamples[2]/exprSize$nSamples[1]);
# Re-plot the dendrograms including the cut lines
pdf(file = "SampleClustering.pdf", width = 12, height = 12);
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
par(mar = c(0, 4, 2, 0))
for (set in 1:nSets)
{
  plot(sampleTrees[[set]], main = paste("Sample clustering on all genes in", setLabels[set]),
       xlab="", sub="", cex = 0.7);
  abline(h=cutHeights[set], col = "red");
}
dev.off();


  #=====================================================================================
#
#  Code chunk 8
#
#=====================================================================================


for (set in 1:nSets)
{
  # Find clusters cut by the line
  labels = cutreeStatic(sampleTrees[[set]], cutHeight = cutHeights[set])
  # Keep the largest one (labeled by the number 1)
  keep = (labels==1)
  multiExpr[[set]]$data = multiExpr[[set]]$data[keep, ]
}
collectGarbage();
 # Check the size of the leftover data
exprSize = checkSets(multiExpr)
exprSize




$nSets
[1] 2

$nGenes
[1] 8213

$nSamples
[1] 0 0

$structureOK
[1] TRUE
```

I think the issue is with the tree cut height because when i check the label all of them are zeroes i guess that is issue so far which is why im getting exprSize nsamples as `0 0`instead of my actual sample size.

I have tried it with different cut height but so far no success may its a pretty simple issue but im not able to figure it out.

Data which im using here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1q6j0UAGxy07TQBd1tbw0XWZAk8LvvieO)

Any suggestion or help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that the cut heights set in the code (80 and 100*ratio of sample numbers) are too low. Look at the sample trees plotted into a pdf file (SampleClustering.pdf) and note the merging heights. You need to set the cut heights appropriately so that most samples go into a single cluster.

Peter

Comment: "(SampleClustering.pdf) and note the merging heights. You need to set the cut heights appropriately so that most samples go into a single cluster." so my y axix upper limit is 120 .Should i set it to 120 as its the highest height .I will attach the fig which was generate for the clustering

Comment: The issue is resolved now